# manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry when pulling from remote repository on artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory, remote-repository

I have configured a remote docker repository on my new artifactory server which points to a virtual docker repo on a legacy artifactory server. I have tested the credentials to access the legacy server and they are working fine from the UI. On the UI for my new artifactory server I can even see the folder structure and all the artifacts from my legacy server. All the artifacts say "this item is not cached". I believe this is expected as it is meant as a representation of my upstream server and nothing has yet been pulled and cached locally.

I have then added this remote repository to a virtual docker repository on the new artifactory server.

The issue is that I am unable to pull items from my legacy server via the newly created remote or virtual repos.

I get the below error

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for obc-test-remote.myartifactoryserver.cloud/base-image:1.1.30 not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry
```

I get the same when I target via the virtual (which has the remote added to it)

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for obc-test-virtual.myartifactoryserver.cloud/base-image:1.1.30 not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry
```

the docker login is succeeded and I am able to pull other docker images with the same syntax from other virtual repos on the same server.

I unticked the option "Block pulling of image manifest v2 schema 1" in the remote repo configuration also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems an issue with the URL configured in the new Artifactory's remote repository. Can you check if this URL includes "api/docker" if not, make sure to have the URL as "http://myold-artifactory.com/artifactory/api/docker/docker-repo-name"

Comment: haha I was just logging back in to post this solution. I had added the /api/docker in the URL and its now working. Thanks for the answer ! :)